# How to delete duplicate records from mysql table but having 1 record

Tags: mysql, duplicates, records

I have a table in mysql which have 1319 duplicate records how can I delete duplicate values but have 1 record saved?

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

First use this kind of query:

```
DELETE FROM comments c1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM comments c2 
              WHERE c2.id <> c1.id 
                AND c2.NAME = c1.NAME 
                AND c2.email = c1.email 
                AND c2.COMMENT = c1.COMMENT)
  AND c1.id <> (SELECT MIN(c2.id) 
                FROM comments c2 
                WHERE c2.NAME = c1.NAME 
                  AND c2.email = c1.email 
                  AND c2.COMMENT = c1.COMMENT)
```

Second:

Create another blank table of same structure and insert into second table using group by on all columns or few unique columns.

Third:

Apply a unique key using alter ignore table.

Comment: Third option worked for me thanks Aman

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

> DELETE FROM tbl
>           WHERE id NOT IN (
>               SELECT * FROM(SELECT id FROM tbl GROUP BY col1, col2, 
>           ) AS p)